# why are ISP's only blocking sub domains and not the full domain

Tags: web, dns, subdomain

Using the popular torrent backdoor come.in as an example, why are only the sub domains being blocked by ISP's?

Originally my ISP blocked eztv.it so I found eztv.come.in which was eventually blocked after some time only to be replaced with ezztv.come.in.

They are now on ezzzztv.come.in and no doubt in time they will be on ezzzzzzzztv.

They also have backdoors to all the other big torrent sites and do the same thing, just open up again with a new sub domain URL

Is there some kind of technical reason that the main domain is not being blocked? Or maybe it's a legal reason. I am no expert but can't think of a logical reason the main domain is not being blocked instead of the ISP playing this cat and mouse game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's anything too mysterious. I'd say it depends heavily on how they are doing the blocking and I'm willing to bet this changes a good bit from ISP to ISP. I would guess that it's one of the following:

1) They get hostnames to block from some source (some kind of commercial feed maybe?), this source gives them the subdomains (i.e. specific hosts instead of a group of hosts), they import this to some list that gets blocked

2) Plain old ignorance or laziness - maybe whatever team is in charge of this just blocks based on hosts because they don't care enough to do basic pattern recognition on hosts they're ordered to block.

3) Technical reasons - maybe whatever tool they use to manage their blacklists only accepts subdomains?

Unless we get someone that does this kind of work for ISPs (and they do it the same way as you are describing), then we'll never know :-)

Comment: No they block the main site first which is not a sub domain. www.eztv.com is blocked.

Comment: Accepted as 42 views in total tells me this will never get a better answer

Answer (score 0):

I do not know why the subdomains are being blocked, however I do know that using a encrypted VPN such as HotspotShield means that your ISPs cannot know what you are visiting (And therefore would have to either block everything or nothing), which means that you can bypass that block.

When I accidentally forgot to pay the bill (Was overdrawn) and my ISP limited me to only Google and Youtube, I used a VPN and was able to access everything fine.

I have only ever used HotspotShield, never used TOR, etc, so I don't know which VPNs it would work with or not (really the question is, which VPNs are encrypted?).

VPNs give higher latency, but to my knowledge do not give slower download speeds (Except if the VPN has a slower internet connection than you), so should be fine for downloads.

Comment: I'm not looking for ways to access. I literally want to understand why they are not blocking the full domain seems really strange

Comment: @Aaron Ah well, might help someone else who stumbles along this page :).

I do not know why it is blocked, unfortunately. There is ISPs for you.